# Find out the primitive polynomial GF(3)

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory, irreducible-polynomials

1.) $x^2 + 2x$
2.) $x^2 + 1$
3.) $x^2 + 2$
4.) $x^2 + 2x$
5.) $x^2 + 2x + 1$
6.) $x^2 + 2x + 2$
7.) $x^2 $
8.) $x^2 + x + 2$
9.) $x^2 + x + 1$

Can any one help me in listing out primitive polynomials and tell me why is it a primitive polynomial please.

Comment: Yes I found these polynomials and don't know how to find primitive polynomial. Its from the subject coding theory

Comment: Can any one help?

Comment: I've posted an answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Hints: A primitive polynomial has to be irreducible. That rules out six candidates. A quadratic primitive polynomial over $GF(3)$ must not be a factor of $x^4-1$. That rules out one more candidate.

Answer (score -3):

$$x^2 + 1,
x^2 + 2x + 2,
x^2 + x + 2,$$
are primitive polynomials over $gf(3)$.
Because they are irreducible and monic polynomials
Monic means coefficient of highest exponent of $x$ is $1$.
And irreducible means can not be further factorise into small polynomials.

Let's take first case $x^ 2 + 2x$ is further factorise as $x(x + 2)$.
Third case $x^2 + 2$ is monic but it is factorise as $(x-1)(x+1)$.
Because in $gf(3), 2 = -1$ and hence $x^2+2 = x^2 -1 = (x-1)(x+1)$.
And you can also check it by taking $x = 1$.

$1^2 + 2 = 3$ which equal to $0$ ( because $3 \pmod3 = 0$) so $x-1$ is factor of $x^2 + 2$  in $gf(3)$.
Now check other polynomials by yourself and get answer.

Comment: $x^2+1$ is not primitive because it is a factor of $x^4-1$. A polynomial over a finite field is said to be primitive if it is the minimal polynomial of a generator of the multiplicative group of an extension field. The zeros of $x^2+1$ are of order four which is less than the required $3^2-1=8$.